# Is it possible to upgrade graphics card in an Omni 120-1120t?

Tags: upgrade, graphics

Is it possible to upgrade graphics card in an Omni 120-1120t? I would like the same level of performance as my other machine which runs an Nvidia GeForce 8800 GTS card. If it is, what card do I need, and what is the process for upgrading the hardware through HP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not really possible, as it doesn't have a separate card the way a desktop and some laptops do;  it has integrated Radeon graphics.  It's inexpensive for good reason, and it will likely never perform the way your other system does.  The point of all-in-one systems is that you get a package that is compact, but not terribly flexible for configuration.